# Using Apache Rewrite Module to do complex Rewriting

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use apache rewrite module to do complex rewriting.

For example
If the url is http://www.site.com/wall and http://www.site.com/profile and http://www.site.com/info I want to rewrite into http://www.site.com/gotopage.php?page=wall ,or http://www.site.com/gotopage.php?page=profile and so forth

But if the url is other than that I want to pass it the other way
For example. if the url is http://www.site.com/newthing then it should rewrite as http://www.site.com/index.php?params=newthing

Please Help. I tried to see other questions but did not get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# Special rule for 3 unique cases
RewriteRule /(wall|profile|info)$ /gotopage.php?page=$1 [L]

# Only rewrite if the URL has not yet been rewritten
RewriteCond %{HTTP_URL} (?!gotopage\.php|index\.php)
RewriteRule /([^/]+) /index.php?params=$1 [L]
```

Here's an explanation, line by line:

1. Any URL that matches one of the 3 specified words gets rewritten to go to `gotopage.php`.
2. This line is a condition for the next line. Only if the URL matches this regex will the next line even be considered. The regex checks to ascertain that the request is not *already* going to `gotopage.php` or `index.php`. If it is, we don't want to rewrite anything (we would just end up in an infinite loop).
3. If the requested URL has no subsequent slashes, rewrite it to go to `index.php`.

Comment: It seems to work i think. But Since I also want it to learn Rewriting and Regexp, Can you elaborate it!

Comment: I tried the code. Put it in .htaccess on my site root on my  local Apache server. It does not seem to work . I have enabled mod_rewrite in apache. And confirmed through http.conf.? Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: @cipher - Don't forget the `RewriteEngine On` part. I just added it to the code above.

Comment: I wrote that already. (Actually that was my first step) I don't know Apache much. I also tried adding `LoadModule mod_rewrite modules/mod_rewrite.so` to the code. Nothing works, I am in panic :(

Comment: I worked on this. But The problem i got is: I placed .htaccess on the site root(say inside htdocs). When i type in localhost/wall it does not seem to work but when i type in localhost/includes/wall. It works. Please HElp